# Feature to remind users to place a bounty

Tags: feature-request, bounty

Often times a question comes along that I really want to know the answer to, but I can see that it has not received much attention yet. I can only place a bounty after some time has passed. Unfortunately, after 2 or 3 days, I often forget to return to the post and place the bounty. Can we implement a feature which alerts the user that a bounty can be placed? Something small like a "Reminder for bounty" bell which you click to be reminded via an inbox message or an email.

Comment: For those curious, this is the post that made me ask this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3692898/can-we-find-a-function-that-finds-the-number-of-points-inside-a-square-centred-o

Comment: If you *really* want to know the answer, you will not forget it in 2 or 3 days.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Fair enough :)

Comment: Perhaps just use a calendar app? If we add too many features to this site, it will lose its simplicity.

Comment: Since were at roughly the same amount of time spent and level of engagement on math.se, I'll mention that lately I've been making a lot more use of the Bookmark function. When I see a post that I think is  interesting but there is no current activity on it and I don't have anything to contribute, I bookmark it. Then about twice a week I check my bookmarks tab and revisit them. How about bookmarking your bounty-worthy posts? [Admittedly one has to check their bookmarks tab. That's a behavior change that's come about slowly, but it has happened for me.]

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Bookmarking (used to be *marking as a favorite*) questions helps a lot. Now that I have 1231 bookmarked question I still need to do a bit of recollecting. The system does raise a flag if there is new activity on a bookmarked question, but in some cases I need to remember to dig a bit deeper! Still, it is a huge help!

Answer (score 1):

Will this help?

[image]

From [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214877/when-is-the-message-have-you-considered-accepting-an-answer-or-starting-a-bount/348533#348533)

> It will be shown for a question if all of the following criteria are true:
>
> - The indicator is enabled for the site (enabled on all sites minus per-site metas, Meta Stack Exchange, and Stack Apps)
> - You are viewing your own questions
> - You have the privilege to vote down
> - You do not have the privilege to cast close votes
> - The question does not have an accepted answer
> - The question is at least three days old and not more than 60 days old
> - The question has at least one answer and is not closed
> - The question does not have a currently active bounty and has not previously had a bounty